# How do I call the same name method from another class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call getX() from JLabel image

.

but my class has int x for its coordinate and getX() method that returns the coorinate x.

For example)

```
class A {

  JLabel image;
  int x =5;

  A() {
    image = some image at some location.
    int a = image.getX();
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;}
  }
```

I'm trying to do

```
int a = image.getX()
```

it should call `getX()` method in JLabel, but it keeps calling the local `getX()` and return the local x value 5.

How do I specify a class when I try to call a method from it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRcyM.png)

Comment: How are you testing this?  It seems hard to believe that image.getX() would return "this.getX()", are you sure that's what's happening?

Comment: This doesn't look like it would return 5... At least not from `class A`. Is this all of your code? Are you printing out `int a` so you can check the result?

Comment: I also think it shouldn't call this.getX(). but it happens :(. I'm using timer to move a JLabel. I'm trying to call image's x value by calling image.getX() which is JLabel and its method. but it keeps calling the local method getX() and return the local vlaue 5...

Comment: Post your actual code instead of this example, it's not here and there may be something suspect about your assignment to `image`.

Comment: Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)